# Django update a static csv file in background everyday at midnight

Tags: python, django, csv, task, schedule

Hi I want to automatically update a static csv file in the background of my django web page every day at midnight, I tried setting a background task so that every day at midnight the file would update, and to test it I would change the schedule value to 1s just so I could see it happening faster but the task would never execute or at least I never saw anything printing in the google devtool nor in the comandline terminal, nor was there any change in modified date in the files properties

my background task

```
@background(schedule= abs(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now().replace(minute=0, second=0, hour=0)))
def update():
    print("in update")
    apiurl = 'https://api_im_downloading_from'
    jasonObject = requests.get(apiurl) 
    parsed = json.loads(jasonObject.text)
    print("downloaded")
    file = open('boards/static/csv_files/file.csv', 'w+', newline='')

    df = pd.json_normalize(parsed) #store parsed jason in a panda data frame
    df.to_csv(r'boards/static/csv_files/file.csv', index=False)
    file.close()
update()
```

my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'boards.apps.BoardsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'background_task',
]
```

when I don't use the  @background and just call my method normally the server crashes, I also tried importing the schedule module and using

```
schedule.every().day.at("0:0").do(update) #change time value to execute faster
```

I also ran this in the commandline and nothing happened

```
python manage.py process_tasks
```

EDIT
I also ran a cronjob

```
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1 # every minute

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS) 
    code = 'my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
        print("in chron job every minute")
        update()
```

But the cronjob required me to run `python manage.py runcrons` in the commandline to do something, but what I want is something that will automatically run the update() function everytime I run the server using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Why not just set a cron job?

Comment: I have no idea what that is, i'm new to django but I will look it up thank you

Comment: It's not part of Django, just Unix/Linux/macOS systems

Comment: I have a windows machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using a batfile to run a task in the windows tasksheduler, details can be found in the following link

https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/